# How to handle different action with same route and different authorize attribute in asp .net core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, authorize-attribute

I'm developing some Web-API project with ASP.Net Core 2 using some custom middleware which is translating the authorization info that it gets from a 3rd party service into a new Claim Identity and adds it to http context user claim principal. I also have implemented some custom authorization policy provider which checks the added claim identity for required permissions and roles.

Now I wanna have two actions like below on same controller with same route:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StatesController : Controller
{

[Authorize("PaiedUser")]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetStates")]
public IActionResult GetStatesPaied(StateHttpRequestParameter requestResourceParameter)
{ //some code here to handle the paied user request} 

[Authorize("FreeUser")]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetStates")]
public IActionResult GetStatesFree(StateHttpRequestParameter requestResourceParameter)
{ //some code here to handle the free user request}
}
```

On the runtime I got this exception,

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

SaMonitoring.API.Controllers.StatesController.GetStatesFree(SaMonitoring.API)
SaMonitoring.API.Controllers.StatesController.GetStatesPaied(SaMonitoring.API)

How can I achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the roles are not mutually exclusive as far as MVC is concerned.  Someone could fall into both conditions which is what makes it ambiguous.  I think you'd be better off checking the user's role inside a single function and providing results appropriately.

Comment: For more information the roles and the permissions are totally mutual exclusive but I got this exception before any role or permission checking and it's odd ! In my pipelines, I have configured MVC as the last middleware but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your solution, but I think is causes somehow a messy actions in controller with bunch of if else conditions.

Comment: As far as the Authorize attribute is concerned they aren't mutually exclusive.  Maybe you have some logic implemented to make sure someone doesn't have both roles/permissions, but no one told the Authorize attribute that.  If you use manager classes to implement your business logic it shouldn't be very messy because your controller would just be responsible for checking the role and delegating the task appropriately.